# Are questions being overvalued?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

During my time here on Stack Overflow, I've tried to answer all of the questions that I know. But there is something that I noticed: some questions have more upvotes than the right answer. Consequently, the author receives more reputation than the one who answered it. I know the question can help the entire community, but I think the right answer helps more.

My idea is to valorize the right answer according to the question; that is, the right answer gains X reputation of each question upvote.

Comment: Answers already get a higher rep value on upvotes (10) vs questions (5).

Comment: And who would decide what the right answer is? Are you talking about giving the accepted answer more points? Because the accepted answer is by no means necessarily the correct answer.

Comment: It happens, not very often.  Not nearly often enough.  A good question can teach the reader a new programming technique he wasn't aware of before.  Or reveal a latent bug or cargo cult in his existing code.  Pretty valuable.

Comment: Yes, but consider some question that receives 1k upvotes, and the right answer just 10

Comment: @TúlioCastro Sounds like an edge case to me. Have any examples? that's out of the norm.

Comment: According to the [Electorate badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), voting on questions is less common than voting on answers.

Comment: Which answer is "*the* right answer"? Remember that the acceptance mark only indicates that the the answer helped the OP at some point in the past,. It is not a "right answer" indicator.

Comment: Sure @KevinB , it is something like this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192745/how-to-center-container-horizontally-but-left-align-child-elements/33294629

Comment: That question had a bounty that ended 11 hours ago. The question having more up votes than the top answer is probably temporary.

Comment: And this why i dislike bounties. That question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527104/left-aligned-last-row-in-centered-grid-of-elements and now i can't close it.

Comment: If I want to vote for an answer, I will. Don't surprise me by giving reputation to one of the answers when I vote for a good question. That's needless complexity.

Comment: @Paulie_D:  To phrase it better, the "accepted" answer indicates that it helped the OP.  Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Yeah... deleted already. Louis already made the point.

Comment: Many of them, yes.  They are a waste of disk space.

Comment: What about answer which come up later and in some cases are better then the accepted answer?

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for introducing me to the word "valorize", which I had never heard before :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions are not over valued. For one, an upvote on a question gets 5 rep versus an answer's 10 rep.

More importantly, without questions you can't have answers. There can be more than one answer to a question. There can be right answers, wrong answers, "more right" and "less right" (but still technically correct) answers. Votes can go to one, all or none of those answers. But, without the question, the answers wouldn't exist.

Answers can also change in value over time. They can become obsolete as programming languages are updated or new libraries are developed. The question, though, remains useful.

Answer (score 10):

> My idea is to valorize the right answer according to the question;
>   that is, the right answer gains X reputation of each question upvote.

- What happens when the selected answer becomes obsolete?
- What if a different answer is the one that helped me? What if *none* of the current answers help me? Why should my vote on the question give rep to an answer that wasn't useful to me?

A vote on a question is not an indicator that any of the existing answers on it were useful or even correct. It doesn't make sense to link the two together.